# How to put a field coming from <xsl: value-of select = "@" /> inside a tag?

Tags: xslt

I can not add within a tag a field with the (`<xsl:value-of select=`)

I'm creating an XSLT template that transforms data from an Excel into XML. Everything is working fine but now I wanted to add to the userdata tag the username of excel (@User_Name).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tXML>
        <Header>
            <Source>TESTE</Source>
            <Action_Type>Upgrade</Action_Type>
            <Message_Type>User</Message_Type>
            <Company_ID>200000002</Company_ID>
            <Msg_Locale>English (United Kingdom)</Msg_Locale>
            <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>08/09/2017 17:35:00</Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
        </Header>
        <Message>               
            <xsl:for-each select="//rs:data">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Message>
    </tXML>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//z:row">
    <UserData  User_Name="{@User_Name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@User_Name"/>
        <User>
            <Company_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Company_Name"/>
            </Company_Name>
            <Location_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Location_Name"/>
            </Location_Name>
            <Role_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Role_Name"/>
            </Role_Name>
            <User_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@User_Name"/>
            </User_Name>
            <First_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@First_Name"/>
            </First_Name>
            <Last_Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Last_Name"/>
            </Last_Name>
            <Solutions>
                <RestrictedSolution>TESTE</RestrictedSolution>
            </Solutions>
        </User>
    </UserData>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample of your input XML please, and the output you expect. Also, is your XSLT complete, as you have referenced the prefixes `rs:` and `z:` in the XSLT but not defined them. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the namespace for XSLT should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` and not `http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl`. The latter is a Microsoft-proprietary draft version of XSLT that became obsolete about 20 years ago!

Comment: Thanks for the help, XSLT is already working properly. I just added the Userdata tag and I want to put the username inside the <xsl: value-of select = "@ User_Name" />

Comment: Thanks for the help, but fortunately I managed to figure out the answer myself.
    '<UserData>
    <xsl: attribute name = "User_Name">
    <xsl: value-of select = "@ User_Name" />
    </ xsl: attribute>
    <UserData />'

Comment: Doing `<UserData  User_Name="{@User_Name}">` should work (This is known as "Attribute Value Templates"). However, it may be that the namespace `http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl` does not support this. But you should really be using `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` anyway, as this is the official one.